# Bengali Family Gotra Brahmarishi

Tags: gotra

My parents said our gotra is "Brahmarishi". But no where I could find about it. Does anyone has more information about this Gotra. Please help me.

Comment: Well, you need to ask *which* Brahmarṣi, the name of the Brahmarṣi. Brahmarṣi (Brahma+r̥ṣi) is just a *r̥ṣi* (sage) who has attained brahmajñāna. Just by that info, you only know that you are from a Brāhmaṇa gotra but not your exact gotra.